# Find a fixed length string with specific string part in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I want to find a string of fixed length with specific substring. But I need to do it like we can do in SQL queries.

Example:
I have strings like -

```
AB012345
AB12345
AB123456
AB1234567
AB98765
AB987654
```

I want to select strings that have `AB` at first and 6 characters afterwards. Which can be done in SQL by `SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE [column_name] LIKE 'AB______'` (6 underscores after `AB`).

So the result will be:

```
AB012345
AB123456
AB987654
```

I need to know if there is any way to select strings in such way with C#, by using `AB______`.

Comment: Uhm..use Regex? `new Regex(@"AB.{6}$")` matches "AB" and any 6 characters afterwards until the end of the line.

Comment: @cubrr, can you please post as an answer? I'm gonna use your way.

Comment: Go ahead and accept @MaciejLos' answer. Change the `\d` to `.` in his Regexp to match any characters after AB instead of any numeral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter the result:

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>(){"AB012345",
            "AB12345",
            "AB123456",
            "AB1234567",
            "AB98765",
            "AB987654"};

var qry = sList.Where(s=>Regex.Match(s, @"^AB\d{6}$").Success);
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have an string array:

```
string[] str = new string[3]{"AB012345", "A12345", "AB98765"};
var result = str.Where(x => x.StartsWith("AB") && x.Length == 8).ToList();
```

The logic is if it starts with `AB`, and its length is 8. It is your best match.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to do it with `AB______` string

Comment: Do you want exclude it? It works fine with this one too, because it starts with "AB" and has 6 characters at the end

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you meant by exclude it. It will be better if anything like `Contains("AB")` could be done. Like if I can select by using `Contains("AB______")`.

Comment: Actually `Contains` matches the strings, you can not use something like this. It will match "_". If you want to create a mask, or something more generic, then `regex` will be the best option for you.

Comment: Then I guess I have to switch to `regex`. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yup, `Regex` is for the more complex matching patterns. Its the best match for your case.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>(){
    "AB012345",
    "AB12345",
    "AB123456",
    "AB1234567",
    "AB98765",
    "AB987654"};

List<string> sREsult = sList.Where(x => x.Length == 8 && x.StartsWith("AB")).ToList();
```

first `x.Length == 8` determines the length and `x.StartsWith("AB")` determines the required characters at the start of the string

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using string.Startwith and string.Length function like this:

```
public bool CheckStringValid (String input)
{
  if (input.StartWith ("AB") && input.Length == 8)
  {
     return true;
   }
  else
  {
     return false;
  }
}
```

This will return true if string matches your criteria.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var strlist = new List<string>()
{
    "AB012345",
    "AB12345",
    "AB123456",
    "AB1234567",
    "AB98765",
    "AB987654"
};
var result = strlist.Where( 
    s => (s.StartsWith("AB") &&(s.Length == 8))
    ); 
foreach(var v in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
}
```